# Python asynchronous file download + parsing + outputting to JSON

Tags: python, python-requests, python-multiprocessing

To briefly explain context, I am downloading SEC prospectus data [for example](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/915802/0001398344-19-002995.txt). After downloading I want to parse the file to extract certain data, then output the parsed dictionary to a JSON file which consists of a list of dictionaries. I would use a SQL database for output, but the research cluster admins at my university are being slow getting me access. If anyone has any suggestions for how to store the data for easy reading/writing later I would appreciate it, I was thinking about HDF5 as a possible alternative.

A minimal example of what I am doing with the spots that I think I need to improved labeled.

```
def classify_file(doc):
    try:
        data = {
            'link': doc.url
        }
    except AttributeError:
        return {'flag': 'ATTRIBUTE ERROR'}
    # Do a bunch of parsing using regular expressions

if __name__=="__main__":
    items = list()
    for d in tqdm([y + ' ' + q for y in ['2019'] for q in ['1']]):
        stream = os.popen('bash ./getformurls.sh ' + d)
        stacked = stream.read().strip().split('\n')
        # split each line into the fixed-width fields
        widths=(12,62,12,12,44)
        items += [[item[sum(widths[:j]):sum(widths[:j+1])].strip() for j in range(len(widths))] for item in stacked]
    urls = [BASE_URL + item[4] for item in items]

    resp = list()
    # PROBLEM 1
    filelimit = 100
    for i in range(ceil(len(urls)/filelimit)):
        print(f'Downloading: {i*filelimit/len(urls)*100:2.0f}%...   ',end='\r',flush=True)
        resp += [r for r in grequests.map((grequests.get(u) for u in urls[i*filelimit:(i+1)*filelimit]))]

    # PROBLEM 2
    with Pool() as p:
        rs = p.map_async(classify_file,resp,chunksize=20)
        rs.wait()
        prospectus = rs.get()
    with open('prospectus_data.json') as f:
        json.dump(prospectus,f)
```

The getfileurls.sh referenced is a bash script I wrote that was faster than doing it in python since I could use grep, the code for that is

```
#!/bin/bash
BASE_URL="https://www.sec.gov/Archives/"
INDEX="edgar/full-index/"

url="${BASE_URL}${INDEX}$1/QTR$2/form.idx"
out=$(curl -s ${url} | grep "^485[A|B]POS")
echo "$out"
```

PROBLEM 1: So I am currently pulling about 18k files in the grequests map call. I was running into an error about too many files being open so I decided to split up the urls list into manageable chunks. I don't like this solution, but it works.

PROBLEM 2: This is where my actual error is. This code runs fine on a smaller set of urls (~2k) on my laptop (uses 100% of my cpu and ~20GB of RAM ~10GB for the file downloads and another ~10GB when the parsing starts), but when I take it to the larger 18k dataset using 40 cores on a research cluster it spins up to ~100GB RAM and ~3TB swap usage then crashes after parsing about 2k documents in 20 minutes via a KeyboardInterrupt from the server.

I don't really understand why the swap usage is getting so crazy, but I think I really just need help with memory management here. Is there a way to create an generator of unsent requests that will be sent when I call classify_file() on them later? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For problem 1, grequests.map has a size parameter: _size: Specifies the number of requests to make at a time. If None, no throttling occurs._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally when you have runaway memory usage with a `Pool` it's because the workers are being re-used and accumulating memory with each iteration.  You can occasionally close and re-open the pool to prevent this but it's so common of an issue that Python now has a built-in parameter to do it for you...

Pool(...`maxtasksperchild`) *is the number of tasks a worker process can complete before it will exit and be replaced with a fresh worker process, to enable unused resources to be freed. The default maxtasksperchild is None, which means worker processes will live as long as the pool.*

There's no way for me to tell you what the right value is but you generally want to set it low enough that resources can be freed fairly often but not so low that it slows things down. (Maybe a minutes worth of processing... just as a guess)

```
with Pool(maxtasksperchild=5) as p:
    rs = p.map_async(classify_file,resp,chunksize=20)
    rs.wait()
    prospectus = rs.get()
```

For your first problem, you might consider just using `requests` and moving the call inside of the worker process you already have.  Pulling 18K worth of URLs and caching all that data initially is going to take time and memory.  If it's all encapsulated in the worker, you'll minimize data usage and you wont need to spin up so many open file handles.

Comment: maxtasksperchild fixes the issue. I moved the requests into the function called by pool. It would be cool to be able to define async def classify_file(x) so that the child worker continues to the next document while the first is downloading. I believe this would cut my runtime in half since downloading the file takes about as long as actually processing it. I'm not sure if there is a way to do that though.

Comment: I would simply set the number of processes in the Pool to a higher number (maybe 2X cpu count).  At first they may start off all downloading together then processing, but after a round or so, I would expect things to stagger a bit so some processes are downloading at the same time others are processing.  If you can set the Pool(N) to some number so all your CPUs are almost maxed, you'll know you're optimized about as good as you can.